# Oozie 4.2.0 build Error with Hadoop 2.7 with Java 1.8

Tags: maven, hadoop, oozie

I am running in pseudo-hadoop mode. with following components
- Hadoop v2.7.0
- Java 1.8+
- Oozie 4.2.0
- OS - Fedora 22 VM
- Maven 3.3

I am having no knowledge about Java or Maven and I am completely new to this world of Build with Maven. I was exploring Oozie and wanted to build it , but every time I try to build it , it fails with the below error. I have search blogs and known blogs (people have mentioned gauravkohli blog, but that doesn't help me either) without much help. Can anyone help me out here?

Secondly, though I have followed a few blogs where they have mentioned that only hadoop version needs to be changed, even then I think I need to change the Hbase and other component versions as they are much higher versions than the ones mentioned in ooze Distro, if any inputs on this also would be of great insights.

```
[INFO]-------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main ..............................SUCCESS [  1.995 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Utils hadoop-2-4.2.0 .......SUCCESS [ 15.697 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp hadoop-2-4.2.0 ......SUCCESS [  1.059 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Auth hadoop-2-4.2.0 Test ...SUCCESS [  0.357 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs .......................SUCCESS [  0.080 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ............................SUCCESS [ 10.525 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ...................SUCCESS [  8.120 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog ................SUCCESS [  4.637 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ..................SUCCESS [  1.528 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core ..............................FAILURE [  5.388 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming ...................SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig .........................SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ........................SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive 2 ......................SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop .......................SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples ..............................SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Spark .......................SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib .............................SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs ..................................SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie .............................SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ................................SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie ZooKeeper Security Tests ..............SKIPPED
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO]-------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 51.047 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-11T12:44:19+11:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 96M/230M
[INFO]-------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:
maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) on project 
oozie-core: Error resolving project artifact: Could not transfer artifact 
org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:pom:5.1.5-jhyde from/to 
Codehaus repository (http://repository.codehaus.org/): 
repository.codehaus.org: unknown error for project org.pentaho:pentaho-
aggdesigner-algorithm:jar:5.1.5-jhyde: Unknown host 
repository.codehaus.org: unknown error -> [Help 1] 
[ERROR]To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven-e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/disp
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the 
command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :oozie-core


                    **[edit]Edited: Vishant : 12-Oct-2015**

After doing some research and editing the pom.xml file. I enadbled the 
REPO1 and  Cloudera repositories, but then I stumbled upon the below 
error. I went ahead and checked the REPO1 repository
 ** DOES NOT have hbase 1.1.2 jars.**

[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Oozie Core 4.2.0
[INFO]-----------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main ..............................SUCCESS[2.334 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Utils hadoop-2-4.2.0 .......SUCCESS[4.010 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp hadoop-2-4.2.0 ......SUCCESS[0.341 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Auth hadoop-2-4.2.0 Test ...SUCCESS[0.688 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs .......................SUCCESS[0.066 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ............................SUCCESS[10.832 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ...................SUCCESS[4.394 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog ................SUCCESS[5.641 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ..................SUCCESS[1.550 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core ..............................FAILURE[0.508 s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive 2 ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Spark ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie ZooKeeper Security Tests .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 32.115 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-12T11:03:04+11:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 100M/239M
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-core: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-core:jar:4.2.0: Failure 
to find org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:1.1.2 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 
was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted 
until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced 
->[Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with 
the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN
/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the 
command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :oozie-core
```

How should I proceed with this? How can I add the jars to my local repository and proceed?

Comment: Can't reproduce after launching `mvn -U clean install -DskipTests=true`. If you are behind a proxy, make sure its configuration in Maven is correct.

Comment: @Tunaki - I did run your command after performing the necessary edits as mentioned in my update, but it failed at Building Hadoop Core. I have also updated the Issue to reflect correct hadoop versions, its Hadoop 2.7 , Java 1.8_45, Hbase 1.1.2, on Fedora 22, Oozie version is 4.2.

Comment: I solved the error. Follow the below steps,   1. Download the jar file Hbase Jar 2.   Edit the ** pom.xml ** to point to the jar file, <dependency>   <groupID>org.apache.hbase</groupID>   <artifactID>hbase</artifactID>  <version>${hbase.version}</version>   <scope>system</scope>   <system>path/to/jar/file/myjar.jar</system>  </dependency>   3. Add the file to the MAVEN repository mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \ -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Apologies as I did NOT have privileges to reply to my own question before!!

**ANSWER:**
I have solved the error. Follow the below steps, but the codehaus stuff doesn't work at all
Step 1. Download the jar file **Hbase Jar**

Step 2. Edit the **pom.xml** to point to the jar file,

```
    <dependency>  
        <groupID>org.apache.hbase</groupID>  
        <artifactID>hbase</artifactID>  
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>  
        <scope>system</scope>  
        <system>system/path/to/jar/file/myjar.jar</system>  
    </dependency>
```

Step 3. Add the **Hbase** file to the MAVEN repository

```
    mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \ -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

**EDITED 13-Jan-2016**
I added the **hbase-common-1.1.2.jar** file, as my verison of hbase was 1.1.2. Please add the hbase-common file as per your version of hbase.

Comment: hbase jar  is   hbase-server-0.98.12-hadoop2.jar  ?   please describe it detail , thanks

Comment: @QinDongLiang - I have added the edit in my answer. Please add the jar file as per your version of hbase installed

Comment: ok , i change it , but run maven still throws this hbase exception, can you share your oozie's pom.xml to me ?  thanks for you .

Answer (score 0):

It is because Codehaus.org no longer hosts maven repos. You can read more at https://www.codehaus.org/mechanics/maven/

In your pom.xml change the url of Codehaus repository to -> https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/

`<repository>
    <id>Codehaus repository</id>
    <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>`

Answer (score 0):

I resolve all problems with this pom.xml as below link
[oozie-4.2 pom.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9mmNG5CxavSMWVhTEM4VjJIeVU/view?usp=sharing)

You can see I change some configuration,including change Codehas respository url
and some others.

```
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
     <artifactId>hadoop-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
<!--<version>${distcp.version}</version>-->

<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
     <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
<!--<version>${hadoop.auth.version}</version>-->
```

You can try this pom.xml to bulid.